# how to associate role id with user model using enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, enums, authorization, roles

I have a simple app with an authentication system from devise. I tried adding roles to the user model. Everything is working perfectly but only when i checked my console it says that role id is nil. I am using `enum` for association beetween role model and user model.

**My user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :shipments
         has_many :comments
         belongs_to :role
         enum role: {shipper: 0, customer: 1, admin: 2}

         def full_name
            first_name + " " + last_name
         end
     end
```

**My role model**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

**addroletouser db file**

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :role, :integer
   end
end
```

**addroleidtouser db file**

```
class AddRoleIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :users, :role, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**My Views file**

```
<div class="row vertical-offset-100">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

    <fieldset>
      <h1 class="text-center login-title"><strong> Get In It's Free!</strong> </h1> 
      <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", label: false %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: "Surname", label: false %>
      <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Email", label: false %> 
      <%= f.input :password, placeholder: "Password", label: false %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Re-enter Password", label: false %>
      <%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons %>
          <div><%= f.button :submit, "Just Sign In!", class: "btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" %></div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="text-center">
        <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <strong><%= link_to "Already On ShiftInd! Login", new_session_path(resource_name) %></strong><br />
<% end -%>
</div>
</fieldset>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch("/assets/shifting.jpg", {speed: 500});
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, because no role was added by you. If you want some default role use `add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0` ...

Comment: `default` can be any value from your enum, like 2, 1, or 0.. It is upto you.

Comment: hey @ArupRakshit thanks. am very new to this stuff can you please tell me where i have to add this line `add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0`

Comment: Is the migration `AddRoleIdToUser` your last migration ?

Comment: nope it was `addroletouser` @ArupRakshit

Comment: You didn't get me.. I see. create another migration to add default value to the field, using http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default method and then apply the migration.

Comment: I live in the central area of kolkata...Nope am just trying to teach myself RoR by some tutorials Googling

Comment: bro it worked but it had given my user a default value that all my users are sellers but i did not want that i want users to chose what role they want to play at the time of signup....sorry i had not added my registration views in my question...but in my views i had added <%= f.association :role, as: :radio_buttons %>....and i want my users to be associated with the role they had choose @ArupRakshit